# GLSL interpolate color tessellation shader

Tags: colors, glsl, shader, interpolation, tessellation

my tessellation shader generates a bezier curve for two vertices.
the vertices consists of two coordinates x and y (vec2).
now every vertex has a color.
my question: how to interpolate the color per vertex on the generated curve?
right now the fragment shader sets a default color value (red).
but i want him to get the interpolated color.

for example:

```
vertex 1 [vec2(0.0, 0.0), vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)] // red
vertex 2 [vec2(1.0, 1.0), vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)] // blue
```

so there should be a gradient from red to blue.
how can i do this with the tessellation shader?

**vertex shader:**

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0 ) in vec2 in_position;
layout (location = 1 ) in vec4 in_color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**tessellation control shader:**

```
#version 400

layout( vertices = 2 ) out;

uniform int NumSegments;
uniform int NumStrips;

void main()
{
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;

    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = float(NumSegments);
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = float(NumStrips);
}
```

**tessellation evaluation shader:**

```
#version 400

layout( isolines ) in;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

void main()
{
    float u = gl_TessCoord.x;

    vec3 p0 = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    vec3 p1 = vec3(0.5, gl_in[0].gl_Position.y, 0.0);
    vec3 p2 = vec3(0.5, gl_in[1].gl_Position.y, 0.0);
    vec3 p3 = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz;

    float u1 = (1.0 - u);
    float u2 = u * u;

    // Bernstein polynomials
    float b3 = u2 * u;
    float b2 = 3.0 * u2 * u1;
    float b1 = 3.0 * u * u1 * u1;
    float b0 = u1 * u1 * u1;

    // Cubic Bezier interpolation
    vec3 p = p0 * b0 + p1 * b1 + p2 * b2 + p3 * b3;

    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * vec4(p, 1.0);
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```
#version 400

layout ( location = 0 ) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
  FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What are `vs_alpha` and `in_alpha`?

Comment: ah sorry, this is a rest from my first try. so just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

This is all pretty straightforward. Just follow the pattern of your already existing inputs and outputs.

Your vertex shader outputs a `gl_Position` value. Therefore, it should also output a color value:

```
layout (location = 0 ) in vec2 in_position;
layout (location = 1 ) in vec4 in_color;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    color = in_color;
}
```

Your tessellation control shader takes an array of `gl_Position`s. So you take an array of colors. It also needs to write to an array of colors:

```
layout( vertices = 2 ) out;

uniform int NumSegments;
uniform int NumStrips;

in vec4 color[];

out Tess
{
  vec4 color;
} Out[];

void main()
{
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
    Out[gl_InvocationID].color = color[gl_InvocationID];

    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = float(NumSegments);
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = float(NumStrips);
}
```

In your evaluation shader, you again need to take an array of input and output layout qualifiers. We used an output interface block called `Tess`, so we need to match it with an input interface block of the same name:

```
layout( isolines ) in;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

in Tess
{
  vec4 color;
} In[];

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    float u = gl_TessCoord.x;

    /** Do whatever interpolation stuff you do **/

    // Cubic Bezier interpolation
    vec3 p = p0 * b0 + p1 * b1 + p2 * b2 + p3 * b3;

    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * vec4(p, 1.0);
    color = Interpolate(In[0].color, In[1].color, ...); //More interpolation stuff.
}
```

And that's that. Your fragment shader takes as an input a `vec4 color`.

Also, a small note: this is not a Bezier spline. Bezier splines require patches of 4 positions, not 2. The way you synthesized the other two values doesn't make them correct.